# What's better use ScrollVIew or use RecyclerView to avoid memory leaks?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, out-of-memory, android-scrollview

I have simple Feed in my app.
On average every user has about 40-50 views in the Feed.
Now I use `ScrollView`and sometimes I have `OutOfMemoryError`(memory leak).
Can using of `ScrollView` be cause of this leaks? And can using of `RecyclerView` 
 help me to avoid them?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use a RecyclerView. A ScrollView suppose a loading all child items at a moment. It's bad practice.
Probably a memory leak does not directly linked with a ScrollView usage and you need to more closely look on your code.

Comment: ok. thanks. but it can be one them?

Comment: No. A proper usage of both of them does not produce a memory leak.